# How to set path to memory card of the mobile?

Tags: qt, audio, nokia, qml

I am using latest qt version 4.7,where i developed an application on Audio Recording.
 I need to set the path to memory card(ie,mass memory),I have seen links based on carbide link->[How to run C++ applications in symbian](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/TSS000220_-_Making_your_Symbian_C++_applications_run_on_S60_devices_from_all_manufacturers) 
But could not find any solution for this latest version.

Can anyone help me out in finding this!!

This is what i tried.
I used two methods but i am clueless….
 But the audio file gets stored in simulator ,,but not in desired memory card location!!!

```
  AudioBuffer::AudioBuffer()
 {
 audioSource = new QAudioCaptureSource();
 capture = new QMediaRecorder(audioSource);

 QAudioEncoderSettings audioSettings;
 audioSettings.setCodec("audio/vorbis");
 audioSettings.setQuality(QtMultimediaKit::HighQuality);
 capture->setEncodingSettings(audioSettings);
 capture->setOutputLocation(QUrl::fromLocalFile("test.wav"));

 FileName path = PathInfo::MemoryCardRootPath();
 path.Append( PathInfo::SoundsPath() );

// QFile file;
// QDir::setCurrent("/tmp");
// file.setFileName("test.wav");
  // QDir::setCurrent("/home");
  // file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
   }
```

I am using Symbian platform(Qt-Quick)

Regards,
Harish.

Answer (score 0):

I don't develop applications for symbian platforms but IMHO you have to convert `TDesC path` to a QString (see [Converting a Descriptor to a QString](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Using_Qt_and_Symbian_C%2B%2B_Together#Converting_a_Descriptor_to_a_QString) for details).

Answer (score 0):

Internal memory is hardcoded to "E:/" and SD card is hardcoded to "F:/" on symbian.

Do a :

```
QDir d;
d.setPath("f:/");
if (d.exists()) {
    [...]
}
```

to check the availability of the external storage